# Python unit tests multiple threads

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm testing an web application and I've already written some tests using unittest. There are some necessary steps like authorization, exchanging data which are being tested and so on. Now I want to test if everything works fine for more then one client. Actually I'd like to call the same test for every client in seperate thread, gather all return codes and print result. My question is how to create such threads in python? (my ad hoc solution in bash spawns multiple python processes)

Let's consider an example:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def testName(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

thread.start_new_thread(unittest.main) #something like this does not work

Comment: you can do it via bash or you use use Popen and open the unittest in a threadpool

Comment: It works pretty good vie bash. I wonder whether this solution is "nice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google around, there are a number of precanned options.  [Nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_multiprocess/multiprocess.html) seems to be a common one.

Otherwise for one of my projects, this worked for my in python 3.3

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Process
    procs=[]
    procs.append(Process(target=unittest.main, kwargs={'verbosity':2}))
    procs.append(Process(target=unittest.main, kwargs={'verbosity':2}))
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

If you only want to run specific tests, then do similar to above but use Suites from [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite).

Comment: I got some problem with passing arguments

Comment: Interesting.  In response to this comment and the follow on post from Adam, I'm wondering if there is a bug in Python2.7 that was fixed in python 3.3 (or earlier).  If you open the file where the problem occurs (multiprocessing/process.py), you can put a str() around the e.arg[0] to get it to work.
sys.stderr.write(**str(e.args[0])** + '\n')